# Mysql UNION ALL query - Too slow using longtext

Tags: mysql, union, big-data

I have this query

```
select t.field1 from (
select t1.field1, t1.field2 from db1.table t1
UNION ALL 
select t2.field1, t2.field2 from db2.table t2
UNION ALL 
select t3.field1, t3.field2 from db3.table t3
) as t
```

field1 is a normal varchar(255) field, but field2 is a longtext field with > 3000 characters of data.

If I am using this query > 20 sec, but if I am using without field2, this query < 2 sec.

Theese tables have 100.000 rows but it will expand.

What is the solution of this problem?

Comment: Please consider reading [this advice](https://dba.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/3034/asking-query-performance-questions)

Comment: *What is the solution of this problem?* Remove `field2` from all subqueries - you do not use them. Moreover, you don't need in outer query, it do nothing and is excess.

Comment: Well, that's I/O for you.

Comment: The Optimizer works pretty hard to deal with things that are under its control.  But it does not bother much with optimizations that _should be_ obvious to the user.

Comment: If the `UNION` is in a `VIEW`, be aware that `VIEWs` are syntactic sugar, and are not well optimized.

Comment: @Akina Current i dont use. But I will use it!